# ¿Cómo ejecutar un activador instalable para cada función?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-apps-script-simple-triggers

No soy muy conocedor de códigos en realidad, pero encontré este tema de activadores instalables que me serviría increiblemente. Al inicio vi que el rango para que se activen es de una hora pero me serviría que sea especifico así que seguí buscando y encontré un código útil.

El código que encontré de hecho funcionó muy bien en las primeras pruebas, pero no sé por qué ahora ya no funciona. Estuve haciendo pruebas para poder correr dos funciones, cada una a hora distinta pero no lo logré y ahora solo tampoco me corre una sola.

Básicamente lo que espero es correr varias funciones a diferentes horas, así como esta función "A" por ejemplo que corra un lunes a las 10:00 PM y una función "B" que corra el mismo lunes a las 11:00 PM

Este es el código que encontré junto con consejos de algunas personas por acá para hacer funcionable el código:

```
    function immutableTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('mutableTrigger')
  .timeBased()
  .everyDays(1)
  .create();
}


function mutableTrigger() {
  const today = new Date();
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const month = today.getMonth();
  const day = today.getDate();
  const functionName = 'A';

  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => {
    if (trigger.getHandlerFunction() === functionName) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
    }
  });
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName)
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(year, month, day, 10, 14))
    .create();
}

function A() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').setFormula('=2+2');;
};

function immutableTrigger2() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('mutableTrigger2')
  .timeBased()
  .everyDays(1)
  .create();
}


function mutableTrigger2() {
  const today = new Date();
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const month = today.getMonth();
  const day = today.getDate();
  const functionName = 'B';

  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => {
    if (trigger.getHandlerFunction() === functionName) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
    }
  });
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName)
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(year, month, day, 10, 15))
    .create();
}

function B() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').setFormula('=4+2');
};


function immutableTrigger3() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('mutableTrigger3')
  .timeBased()
  .everyDays(1)
  .create();
}


function mutableTrigger3() {
  const today = new Date();
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const month = today.getMonth();
  const day = today.getDate();
  const functionName = 'C';

  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => {
    if (trigger.getHandlerFunction() === functionName) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
    }
  });
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName)
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(year, month, day, 10, 16))
    .create();
}

function C() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').setFormula('=4+2');
};
```

Por acá también dejo la hoja de Google que estoy usando: [Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13YTH-HGMd5FYZ4D7FhTq6Numa1oS_scUBnh161XyjAg/edit?usp=sharing)

Por acá dejo también los registros de ejecución los que parecen no mostrar ningún problema: [image: Ejecución]

Llevo meses en esto :( así que estaré muy agradecido si alguien me puede ayudar. :)

Answer (score 0):

Debes crear un activador instalable para cada función. Una manera de hacerlo modificar `const functionName = 'A';` ya sea que lo ejecutes una vez y luego lo modifiques para cada función y repitas hast completar o bien puedes hacer algo más elegante como usar un bucle para lo cual podrías declarar un Array con los nombres de las funciones para las cuales quieres crear el activador instalable.

---

La función A es ineficiente, no tiene sentido activar las celdas cuando se está actualizando el spreadsheet con un activador basado en tiempo. Mejor agrega la fórmula directamente al rango:

```javascript
function A() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').setFormula('=2+2');
};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda @Rubén De hecho sí intenté crear un activador para cada función pero a partir de eso solo dejó de funcionar y aunque cambie la hora no se ejecuta, no sé si estoy equivocado pero solo repliqué el código que puse por acá cambiando la hora, la función a ejecutar y la parte que mencionas. Crees que pueda estar haciendo algo mal? O ves bien el código y tal vez pueda ser algo más?

Te agradezco inmensamente por la ayuda

Comment: ¿Cómo estás revisando que el código funciona o no? ¿Te estas asegurando que el activador se programe para ejecutarse después de la hora actual o has puesto horas que ya pasaron?

Comment: Fijate que sí estoy poniendolo en horas próximas cercanas, incluso puse la zona horaria de mi País (GTM-6) para ver si podría estar tomando otra pero simplemente no se ejecuta

Comment: Y para revisarlo lo estoy ejecutando, no me tira ningún error y lo que me parece raro es que en las primeras pruebas sí me funcionó normal

Comment: Te sugiero editar la pregunta para mostrar la modificación que has realizado al código original así como incluir los registros de ejecución.

Comment: Sí, con gusto! Ahora mismo no estoy en mi casa pero solo regrese la edito con el código para que se vea lo que hice. Muchas gracias Rubén!

Comment: Hola @Rubén, actualicé el código en mi pregunta y agregué una captura del registro de ejecución. Cuando ejecuto simplemente aparece en el mismo momento la fórmula de la función "A"en la celda esperada pero no pasa en el tiempo que he configurado para que pase. También está incluída la hoja de Google con el código para verlo mejor.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda, se aprecia inmensamente. Saludos!